# Capture url inside method onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

How can i capture the url when the method *onBackPressed* is fired?

I already tried use the method *getUrl()*, but it brings me a url of the page i'm on and not the page I came back to.

I need the behavior that the method *shouldOverrideUrlLoading* has, but inside the *onBackPressed* (because i need to do the same condition).

Is there a way to do this?

PS: I'm using an *WebView*.

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    String mosaicUrl = "https://www.mosaicapp.com.br";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        myWebView.loadUrl(mosaicUrl);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_error);
            }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                int slashslash = url.indexOf("//") + 2;
                String domain = url.substring(slashslash, url.indexOf('/', slashslash));

                ImageView imageview = findViewById(R.id.imageBack);

                if (domain.equals("www.mosaicapp.com.br")) {
                    imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

        // Enable JavaScript
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Return to Home
        ImageView imageBack = findViewById(R.id.imageBack);
        imageBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                myWebView.loadUrl(mosaicUrl);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your webView settings?

Comment: I edited the post with the whole activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is ask for pageFinish, once the page finishes loading, you have to ask for the current url:

```
public String currentUrl = "";
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        currentUrl = webView.getUrl();
    }

});
```

This should do the job.

Comment: But in this way how can i capture the url?

Comment: Let me change it, I got the wrong idea on what you were asking for.